# ¿Cómo manejar la respuesta de google desde /auth/google/callback?

Tags: nodejs, angularjs, oauth2

Estoy implementando en mi aplicación la autenticación con oauth2 para hacer un mecanismo de SSO. La aplicación está desarrollada en AngularJS con NODEJS de backend.

Estoy teniendo problemas al pasar datos del endpoint de mi API ('/auth/google/callback') al controller, para así poder manejar la sesión de usuario y mantenerla iniciada.

La llamada a la URL la realizo mediante "$window.location.href = '/auth/google'" y de ahí redirige a "/auth/google/callback", por lo que no he encontrado forma de meterlo dentro de una promesa y poder recepcionar los datos devueltos por google.

La forma en la que envío los datos desde el router sería usando el objeto res, pero esto envía los datos directamente a la ventana del navegador, no tendría forma de manejarlos en el controller.

```
res.send(req.user);
```

PD: No utilizo el método GET de HTTP porque al hacer la llamada con GET, me bloquea la respuesta debido a una violación de las CORS policy.

¿Alguien podría darme una idea de cómo pasar estos datos desde el endpoint de mi API al controller de AngularJS?

Muchas gracias.